# How to set up Navigation Properties to enforce deleting related records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, relationship

I am using MVC 4 and VS2010 with Entity Framework 6.1.x. I am working with a Code First fairly easy database but there is a slightly more complex part of it. First of all, two tables `Person` and `Recording` have relationship 1 to many.

```
public class Person {
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public int GenderID { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public virtual List<Recording> Recordings { get; set; }
}

public class Recording {
    public int RecordingID { get; set; }
    // ...
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Junction> Junctions { get; set; }
}
```

By default, when I delete a `Person`, Entity Framework deletes all recordings related to `Person`. That's what I expect. But the records from `Recording` table are also placed in different set of tables. Let's say I have table called `Applicant`, `Application` and `Junction`. When I delete any recording either by deleting `Person` or `Recording`, I would like all records in `Junction` which are related to records in `Recording` to be deleted, as well. In my project it wouldn't make sense if there are zero number of recordings associated with particular application.

There is a combined `Primary Key`, that is `ApplicantID`, `ApplicationID`, and `RecordID` in `Junction` make the complex Key.

Is it possible to enforce constraints via Entity Framework or I'd rather have to provide my own custom function?

How to set up Navigation properties in corresponding tables: `Recording` and `Junction` so that related recordings are deleted?

```
public class Applicant
{
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public virtual List<Junction> Junctions { get; set; }
}

public class Application {
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public virtual List<Junction> Junctions { get; set; }
}    

public class Junction
{
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
    public int RecordingID { get; set; }

    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
    public virtual Recording Recording { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

---

EDIT

@Chris. From what I have understood, if a Foreign Key is not nullable, records in the secondary table are deleted if a record in the Primary table with the corresponding PrimaryID are deleted. On the other hand, if the Foreign Key is nullable, records in the secondary table, would become `null` but not deleted.

I made this project and two tables and I filled the database. In the class `Student`, if I leave `DepartmentID` not nullable,

```
public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
```

records are deleted when a record with primary `DepartmentID` is deleted. This is what I expect but if I make `DepartmentID` nullable

```
public int? DepartmentID { get; set; }
```

then I've got this error:

> *The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Student_dbo.Department_DepartmentID". The conflict occurred in database "TestDB", table "dbo.Student", column 'DepartmentID'.
>
>   The statement has been terminated.*

In test project I made two tables with relationship 1 to many.

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class Student : IDisposable
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Is this what I should expect?

Comment: The relationship between `Junction` and `Recording` is a many-to-many I'm assuming?

Comment: @IronMan84 Yes the relationship is many-to-many

Answer (score 1):

The delete cascade is not intended to just delete items on a whim. It exists out of necessity. In your example above, `Recording` has a non-nullable foreign key to `Person`. If that `Person` is deleted, the foreign key would either have to be set to null (which can't happen) or all related `Recording`s must be deleted to preserve referential integrity.

In the second example with `Junction`, there's a non-nullable foreign key to `Record`. So if you delete a `Person` all related `Record`s and all `Junction`s related to those records should be deleted. However, if you delete a `Junction` no further action is taken. There is nothing inherently dependent on a `Junction` so its deletion goes unnoticed. Any `Record`s it once referenced are still valid. Remember this is all about maintaining referential integrity. As long as integrity is intact, nothing will ever be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's really good explanation. Many things make sense to me now.

Comment: I have edited the question. There is one thing confusing me. I hope it's ok if you can comment on the edited part. Basically, I am confused about nullable Foreign Key. Cheers!

Comment: I found the answer here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj679962.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj679962.aspx)